# CNContactPicker - User cannot select Contact after using Search

Tags: swift, macos, cncontactpicker

I have an OSX app that uses CNContactPicker to import details of a single Contact that the user selects. If the user enters the Contact Picker and uses the Search bar to return a single contact (i.e. there is only one result in the list) - this contact cannot be selected. It works fine if the user search returns multiple contacts (i.e. they can select a single contact from a list of multiple contacts).

As an example: I created a Contact called "Testing". In this screenshot you will see I searched for Testing and there is 1 result in the search list. I cannot select this Contact.

[image]

It looks like an Apple bug to me, but I would like to know if anyone else using CNContactPicker in a Mac app has the same issue?

Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func importContacts(_ sender: NSButton) {
    popover = CNContactPicker()
    (popover! as! CNContactPicker).delegate = self
    (popover! as! CNContactPicker).showRelative(to: self.view.bounds, of: self.view, preferredEdge:NSRectEdge.maxX)
}

func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPicker, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
    importedContact = contact
}

func contactPickerDidClose(_ picker: CNContactPicker) {
    if (importedContact != nil) {
        self.populateDetailsFromContact(importedContact! as! CNContact)
    }
}
```

The "didSelect" delegate function does not fire in this scenario, so my "importedContact" variable is nil. I have reproduced the scenario in a small project.

Comment: Is it possible to pick this contact if it's in a list with other contacts? Post a [mre] please.

Comment: Yes as mentioned above, a contact can be selected if it is in a list with other contacts. If a contact is on its own in the list, it cannot be selected. It should be reproducible given my original example. 1. Run the CNContactPicker. 2. Do a search that results in a single contact. 3. Try to select that contact.

Comment: I've already done this and I don't see any issues. Which `displayedKeys`? Which `CNContactPickerDelegate` methods are implemented? What happens when you try to select that contact? Is it possible to reproduce the issue in a small test project?

Comment: Hi, could you please reopen this post? It is still an issue for me. I have added some code and a screenshot for clarification and have reproduced the issue on a small test project.

Comment: It looks like a bug. I don't see any issues on macOS 10.13. On macOS 10.15 the first found contact isn't selectable.

Comment: Thankyou for confirming. I have submitted the bug details to Apple. I will update here when I hear back.